# How to put two values from a single line into two variables in bash?

Tags: bash

For example, instead of doing

```
start=`commandforstdout | awk {'print $2'}`
end=`commandforstdout | awk {'print $5'}`
```

Is there a way to store

```
`commandforstdout | awk {'print $2, $5'}`
```

into two different variables without having to run the command a second time? Just for the sake of efficiency...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `read` builtin with **process substitution**:

```
read start end < <(commandforstdout | awk {'print $2, $5'})
```

Or even without awk (thanks to @gniourf_gniourf):

```
read -r _ start _ _ end _ < <(commandforstdout)
```

Comment: For bonus points, tell both `read` and `awk` to use a unique delimiter.

Comment: Oh yes that will be even better, thanks @gniourf_gniourf

Answer (score 2):

The posixly portable way to do this without coprocesses or bashisms:

```
set -- $(commandforstdout | awk '{print $2, $5}')
start=$1 end=$2
```

This could be even easier if you tell us the output of `commandforstdout`. It might be that

```
set -- $(commandforstdout)
start=$2 end=$5
```

would even save the expensive fork and pipe. As gniourf_gniourf rightfully noted, pathname expansion may get in the way if the result contains glob characters. Should this be a problem, use `set -f` before the first `set` and `set +f` if you need pathname expansion later on again.

Comment: Maybe it's portable and POSIX, but it's broken: pathname expansion occurs! how about: `read -r _ start _ _ end _ <<EOF` and `$(commandforstdout)` and `EOF` (on three different lines).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Ugh. Unused repeated dummys with underscores. I'd rather `set -f` to switch off pathname expansion, if it can get in the way.

Comment: This is rather common `:)` at least as long as it's manageable.

Comment: The output is that of a readelf -W -l on a memory dump from Virtualbox. I was writing a script to do the dump and parse out the part of the file that's compatible with volatility, and figured there had to be a way to make it more efficient. I can't remember all of the output off-hand, but the line I want is something like LOAD then six hex values and a flag character value of some kind. I'm using grep and awk to pull out the start of the section in bytes, and the size, then cut it up with tail and head -c.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the helpful existing answers:

The reason a straightforward pipeline solution (`commandforstdout | read ...`) doesn't work is that **all commands in a pipeline are by default run in a *sub*shell**, so that the variables that a `read` command in a pipeline creates will *not* be visible after the pipeline.

However, on **bash 4.2+**, turning on **shell option `lastpipe` causes the *last* pipeline segment to run in the *current* shell**, allowing `read` to create variables visible to the current shell.

Example:

```
# bash 4.2+: Turn on shell option that runs the *last* pipeline segment in the
#            *current shell* rather than in a *subshell*.
shopt -s lastpipe

# Read the two words piped via stdin into two variables.
# Since option `lastpipe` is on, the variables are created in the *current* shell.
echo 'START END' | read -r start end  

echo "[$start] [$end]"  # -> '[START] [END]'
```

Note: `lastpipe` only works when job control is turned *off*, which is true by default in non-interactive shells (e.g., in *scripts*), but not true in *interactive shells*; to test the example above interactively, you must turn job control (temporarily) off:
`set +m; shopt -s lastpipe && echo 'START END' | read -r start end; echo "[$start] [$end]"; set -m`